# vprintf() with too few arguments

Tags: php

I have this php error, but the script works. I think the first `vprintf()` is correct, only the second `vprintf()` have this error.

```
vprintf(): Too few arguments 

function CreateLangTable($csvFile, $startRow, $endRow, $number) {
    global $lang_code1, $lang_code2, $vocabulary_group, $teilurl;

    if ($endRow < $startRow) {
        return;
    }
    echo ' 
  <a id="' . $vocabulary_group[$teilurl[4]][$number] . '"></a>      
  <table class="table-vocabulary">                           
    <thead>';
    $csvFile->seek($startRow);

    vprintf('
        <tr>
          <th><div data-text="%1$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code1 . '" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</div></th> 
          <th><div data-text="%2$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code2 . '" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>', $csvFile->current());

    while ($csvFile->key() <= $endRow) {
        $csvFile->next();

    vprintf('   
        <tr>
          <td><div data-text="%1$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code1 . '" class="trigger_play"> %1$s</div></td> 
          <td><div data-text="%2$s" data-lang="' . $lang_code2 . '" class="trigger_play"> %2$s</div></td>
        </tr>', $csvFile->current());
    }

    echo '
    </tbody>
  </table>' . "\n";
}
```

I have read in another answer for a problem with sprintf() toescape the `$` as `\$`, but then I would get many of this errors.

example csv file

```
th-value 1,th-Wert 1
value 2,Wert 2
value 3,Wert 3
value 4,Wert 4
value 5,Wert 5

th-value 1,th-Wert 1
value 2,Wert 2
value 3,Wert 3
value 4,Wert 4
value 5,Wert 5
```

I had used this code to generate the correct table:

```
CreateLangTable($file, 0, 4, 0);
CreateLangTable($file, 6, 9, 1);
```

If I change 4 to 3 and 9 to 8 the errors are gone, but why?

Comment: When your reach the last element of `$csvFile` doing `next` fetches you what?

Comment: @u_mulder I have posted now  the whole function.

Comment: It seems @u_mulder suggested that you to check the contents from `$csvFile->current()` after you reach `$endRow`. You can use XDebug to find that out, or simply add a `var_dump($csvFile->current())` inside your loop, just after `$csvFile->next()` to check the value for each row. This way you can confirm if you actually have an array with at least two values for all rows.

Comment: Ok, I think I have found the error, but I don't understand it correct. I will add an example.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that you move pointer in a `$csvFile` **before** you get current value.

So when pointer point to your last element, you move it forward using `next`. So what is current element now? I think it's NULL.

All you have to do is use `next` **after** `vsprintf`
Or maybe use `valid` to check if current value is a valid value.

Comment: Thank you. I have used `next` after  `vsprintf ` and the error is gone, so I don't have to change the values for the second paramteter.

Comment: When I use `next` after `vsprintf` the script will generet two times the values from the first line, first as a `<th>` and then like the others in `<td>`. It should only show it in the `<th>`

Comment: If I put `$csvFile->next(); `  before the `while`-loop I would get a  infinite loop for printing the first `<td>`  values